# Remove root path from url

Tags: php, mysql

I'm writing parser which will add posts to database using `INSERT INTO`.
Now it comes turn to images. Tried to add simple URL to image field like this: `http://example.com/image.jpg`

[image]

Website returned me this path of image
`<img src="http://127.0.0.1/uploads/images/http://example.com/image.jpg">`

instead

`<img src="http://example.com/image.jpg">`

I tried to add `../../../http://example.com/image.jpg` in phpMyAdmin but it didn't help. Is there any solution to make this working without editing core files of CMS.

**Code:**

```
<div class="featured-img">
    <?php
        $v = (set_value('featured_img')!='') ? set_value('featured_img') : $post->featured_img;
    ?>
    <input type="hidden" name="featured_img" id="featured-img-input" value="<?php echo $v;?>">
    <img id="featured-img" src="<?php echo base_url('uploads/images/no-image.png');?>">
    <div class="upload-button"><?php echo lang_key('upload');?></div>
    <?php echo form_error('featured_img');?>
</div>
```

This happens because `echo base_url` but I can't remove it because in future users will upload there images also, any suggestions?

Comment: The problem is probably not the inserting but the display, it seems like you prepend `http://127.0.0.1/uploads/images/` to the value received from the db. Can you post the code (in the question itself, not comments please)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quick solution to determine wheter or not the image is on the server could be something like

```
if (stripos($image, 'http') === 0)
```

which will check if the string begins with `http`. If it does, you do not need to apply `base_url()`

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to write `base_url()` in this case, just write

```
<img src="<?php echo $post->featured_img;?>">
```

**Suggestion**:- It is not good idea to store whole image path in DB.
Just store image name in DB.

Then just define one **constant** for image path,

```
define('IMAGE_PATH','http://example.com/');
```

then use it as

```
<img src="<?php echo IMAGE_PATH.$post->featured_img;?>">
```